# MATLAB: "ismember" function for a nx1 Char

Tags: matlab, function, char, find

Good day.

I'm trying to find the spaces in a sentence using "ismember" function for a nx1 Char.

Here I have a working example for a 1x1 Char:

```
    %% Working example
    StringSearchedSpaces = ' ' ; %White spaces
    
    String1 = "Random info - at beginning-man. "+ ...
            "Random info still continues. ";
    
    Char1 = convertStringsToChars(String1);
    
    String1Spaceidx = ismember(Char1, StringSearchedSpaces);
```

Notice this returns "0" if a character is not a 'space', and "1" if it is a 'space'. Now, I would like to apply the same logic for a nx1 Char, see my attempt:

```
%% Not Working example
String2 = ["Random info in middle one, "+ ...
        "Random info still continues. ",
        "Random info in middle two. "+ ...
        "Random info still continues. "];

Char2 = convertStringsToChars(String2);

%PlanA
PlanAString1Spaceidx = ismember(Char2, StringSearchedSpaces);
%PlanB
for z=1:length(Char2)
PlanBString2Spaceidx(z,:) = ismember(Char2(z,:), StringSearchedSpaces);
end
```

Both plans for some reason do not return "0" and "1" values, which indicate the locations of 'spaces'. But, only return "0"?

What can I do to receive answer correctly, and in the same format as the "Working Example" (using a 1x1 Char), but now for a nx1 Char?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: much better to use `strfind`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case `convertStringsToChars` will return a `cell` array. You will have to apply the `ismember` functio on every cell in the array, e.g. by using `cellfun`:

```
space_idx_char2 = cellfun(@(s) ismember(s, StringSearchedSpaces),Char2, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Alternatively, you can use the for loop, but you have to change the brackets a bit:

```
PlanBString2Spaceidx = cell(size(Char2)); % initialize empty cell array
for z=1:length(Char2)
    PlanBString2Spaceidx{z,:} = ismember(Char2{z,:}, StringSearchedSpaces);
end
```